# What is the cost and schedule of the bus between Alat and Baku in Azerbaijan?

Tags: buses, azerbaijan, baku

What does the bus between the Alat port and Baku cost? I will be arriving in Alat on a Ferry from Aktau (Kazakhstan) and need to get to Baku from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No buses from the port, only taxis to a bus stop a few km away. Costs roughly AZN 5.

The 195 bus from central Alat to Baku costs AZN 0.80

Comment: @pnuts Every 30 minutes after 18:00. Did the trip in July